# max_execution_time in php.ini wont update, other settings will

Tags: windows, iis-6, php

So I've edited my php.ini file to allow for a longer max_execution_time, among some other settings.  When I recycle the application pool in IIS 6 on windows server 2003 and check the php info file I've created, the other settings I've changed stick, but max_execution_time stays at it's default setting (300).  What's up?  It is not commented out and looks like this:

```
max_execution_time = 1800
```

Like I said, I've changed max_input_time to have the same value, and it works.

```
max_input_time = 1800
```

Reading a PHP Info file shows that the max_input_time is 1800 seconds, but max_execution_time still says 300.  Thoughts on this?

Edit: The Loaded Configuration File listed within the phpinfo file is the file I'm working with.  As I mentioned, other settings are taking effect, however, this specific setting is not.  This means that it is indeed reading the file I'm editing, it just doesn't want to change the max_execution_time. I've also restarted the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try you can try to use `set_time_limit(0)`;

Comment: This works at the file level, yes, but I'm looking for a server wide solution.

Answer (score 1):

please check your php.ini path first after then change in correct file.

or

if you change correct file then restart server

Comment: The Loaded Configuration File listed within the phpinfo file is the file I'm working with. As I mentioned, other settings are taking effect, however, this specific setting is not. This means that it is indeed reading the file I'm editing, it just doesn't want to change the max_execution_time. I've also restarted the server.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I have the same issue with max_input_vars